# How to make the body of a loop awaited?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have two functions that work, let's independently. One generates data inside a loop and and saves them on a db. The other is pinging the db every few seconds and if new data have been saved it plots them. In pseudocode it looks like:

```
def dashborard():
    ping_db(time_interval)
    if new_values:
        plot(new_values)

def generate_data(d):
    ## do something with d
    ## and return some values
    return values

for i in range(10):
    generate_data(i)
```

I would like to run the dashboard and the data-generating loop asynchronously but I havent managed to do it unless I put an `await asyncio.sleep()` call inside the function the runs the loop. Again, in pseudocode this is what I have done:

```
import asyncio

def run_async(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    return result

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(dashboard())
    out = await self.run_loop()
    return out

async def run_loop(self):
    for i in range(10):
        values = await generate_data(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(some_seconds) ## <---- How can I remove this?
    return values
```

The `await asycion,sleep()` argument is at least the number of seconds each loop takes. In this case, the dashboard opens and works fine. If I remove it however, then the dashboard doesnt open until we reach the very end of the loop.

How can I have the loop and the dashboard run asynchronously please? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `generate_data` do? Note: Unless `generate_data` is an IO bound method `asyncio` isn't going to provide any value over a normal single threaded application.

Comment: I dont want to speed it up. The dashboard needs to run asynchronously because if it is done sequentially, the code that generates the data is never reached

Answer (score 0):

The `(self)` pieces in your code suggest use of a class??? Can't figure this. However assuming these are in the same event loop (otherwise why use asyncio???) the following illustrates an approach using asyncio Queues.

```
import asyncio

async def dashboard(queue):
    while True:
        new_value = await queue.get()
        if new_value == '__END__':
            return
        print(new_value)

async def generate_data(i):
    """
    Presumably your database access awaits the database update.
    Unless you await something here the co-routines cannot co-operate.
                                        -----------        ----------
    """
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return f"something from {i}"

async def run_loop(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    values = []
    for i in range(5):
        value = await generate_data(i)
        values.append(value)
        queue.put_nowait(value)
        # await asyncio.sleep(some_seconds)  # <---- How can I remove this?
    queue.put_nowait('__END__')
    return values

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    last = asyncio.create_task(dashboard(queue))
    out = await run_loop(queue)
    print(out)
    await asyncio.gather(last)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is:

```
something from 0
something from 1
something from 2
something from 3
['something from 0', 'something from 1', 'something from 2', 'something from 3', 'something from 4']
something from 4
```